# Combine powershell commands

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Guys I have this unique problem and have been stomping my head for answers. I basically have two good running scripts but I need to combine them. For some reason this is not working and I am getting all types of syntax powershell errors.

1st script which works correctly. Please see below for the second script

```
Get-Content c:\list.txt | foreach {
    Get-Mailboxstatistics -id $_ | foreach{
        $mbx = $_ | select DisplayName, @{Label=’MailboxSize("MB")’;Expression={$_.TotalItemSize/1MB}}, ItemCount
        $date_captured=get-date | select datetime

        Get-Mailbox -id $_ | foreach{
            $mbx | add-member -type noteProperty -name Alias -value $_.Alias
            $mbx | add-member -type noteProperty -name ServerName -value $_.ServerName
            $mbx | add-member -type noteProperty -name ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -value $.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota 
            $mbx | add-member -type noteProperty -name UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults -value $.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults 
            $mbx | add-member -type noteProperty -name IssueWarningQuota -value $_.IssueWarningQuota
        } $mbx, $date_captured

    }

}
```

Here is the second command that runs. This works great by itself and again trying to

combine this with the command above this fails.

```
get-mailboxfolderstatistics -id "alias" | select name, foldersize, itemsinfolder
```

Now what I am trying to accompish is to get my output to something like this below.

> DisplayName               MailboxSize("MB")         ItemCount
>   Alias                     ServerName
>   ProhibitSendReceiveQuota  UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults  IssueWarningQuota
>
> DateTime : Tuesday, April 10, 2012 4:04:28 PM
>
> Name          Foldersize  Itemsinfolder topofinfromationstore 0       3 calendar
>   1234      54 inbox            1024785     241 sent items      14745       54               deleted
>   items     5414745     875

Comment: Not clear on what you are asking. Also, your 1st "working" script has syntax errors.

Comment: I got a funny feeling that I am missing } . I was at work when I did this and unfortunately not at a machine to run this. I am almost sure it is missing a "}" bracket. Also I am just trying to combine the script at the top along with the following command. I would like the output to go to one file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Out-File` to log the output of both commands e.g.:

```
<first-command> | Out-File c:\log.txt
<second-command> | Out-File c:\log.txt -Append
```

Or if you prefer redirection operators:

```
<first-command>   > c:\log.txt
<second-command> >> c:\log.txt
```

Comment: this actually worked like a charm. I am trying to get this to go into excel now. I have been reading where I can make this tab deliminited.

Comment: @user1324990 You can use something like this to export as TSV:  `$output = @(<first-command>); $output += @(<second-command>); $output | Export-Csv C:\log.csv -delimiter "``t"`

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question what I think you want to do is combine the results of two commands so that you end up with a new object.  This code will write a custom object to the pipeline with the values you seem to be after. To save to a file run your script and pipe it to Out-File or anything else.

```
Get-Content c:\list.txt | foreach {
Get-Mailboxstatistics -id $_ | foreach-object {
    #define a hash table of properties
    $size=($_.TotalItemSize)/1MB
    $props=@{
    MailboxSizeMB=$size;
    Displayname=$_.DisplayName;
    ItemCount=$_.ItemCount;
    DateCaptured=Get-Date;
    } #close hash

    Get-Mailbox -id $_ | foreach-object {
        $props.Add("Alias",$_.Alias)
        $props.Add("ServerName",$_.ServerName)
        $props.Add("ProhibitSendReceiveQuota",$_.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota)
        $props.Add("UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults",$_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults)
        $props.Add("IssueWarningQuota",$_.IssueWarningQuota)
    } #foreach mailbox

    #write a custom object
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

} #foreach mailboxstatistic
```

} #foreach content

Comment: I am sorry about getting back so late. I like what you have done with the commands and making them a hash. This gives me a lot of thought about other things I can use this for. From your example though however, I still cannot get the command get-mailboxfolderstatistics entered into the commands above.